# How to implement IEnumerable<T> on nested Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, ienumerable

I have this class:

```
public class MyClass<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, Dictionary<T, double>> data = new Dictionary<T, Dictionary<T, double>>();

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        //Return what???
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

But how do I implement `GetEnumerator`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionary has `Keys` collection of type `T`:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return data.Keys.GetEnumerator();
}
```